# Timeout error while using powershell to run SQL query

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2012

```
Function Run-SqlQuery 
    {
        param([string]$server = ".", [string]$database, [string]$query)
        $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=$server;Initial Catalog=$database ; Connection Timeout=0 ; Integrated Security=SSPI;")
        $adapter    = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($query, $connection)
        $set        = New-Object System.Data.DataSet                                                                                                                                     
        $adapter.Fill($set) > $null
            $table      = $set.Tables[0]
                return $table
            }

            $data = run-sqlquery -server $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SRVR)) -database dba -query "exec dba.dbo.DBASP_HTML_HealthReport"


            $data["Column1"]
```

for the above query, I am getting below error:

> The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Exception calling
>   "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Timeout expired.  The timeout period
>   elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not
>   responding. The statement has been terminated."

Please any help is appreciated.

Comment: First of all check if you actually having a connection: $connection.Open()